Detecting and fixing clipped positive waveforms
I have a large number of audio files recorded using custom IOT devices. When analysing the data I noticed that a portion of them seems to have their positive amplitude ramp up, but the negative portion of the amplitude seems fine. Here are examples:


I am wondering if:

This is possible to detect programmatically (python, numpy, librosa)
Given audio is a sign wave, can it also be fixed programmatically?



This is possible to detect programmatically (python, numpy, librosa)

Yes. There are bunch of different ways:
If your signal is known to be DC free (which would be expected from most audio sources and your signals sure look like it), than you can simply look for significant asymmetry between positive and negative short term peaks.
If that's a not a safe assumption you can look at the variance of the short term peaks. If neighboring short team peaks are very close, than it's clipped.
If you want to be more formal, you can calculate a running PDF (probability density function) and look for the specific pattern of your problem.

Given audio is a sign wave, can it also be fixed programmatically?

I'm assuming you mean the sine function (sin(x)) and not the signum function (sign(x)) but in either case the answer is yet. If you know it's a sine (or signum for that matter) you only need a handful of "known good samples" to reconstruct the correct waveform . The details will depend on your requirements and signal to noise ratio.
This being said, that device is doing horrible damage to the audio signal and reconstructing any "normal" audio signal recorded this way would be very difficult. You should really go back to the source and ask them to fix this problem. This is a serious bug and there is no need for that.
